# query only recalled record for approval process

Tags: soql, approval-process, custom-reports, approval-history

I have a requirement in which I need to query only those record which are recalled, is it possible for using query or through report.

Comment: Can you try `SELECT Id, Status, TargetObject.type, CompletedDate FROM ProcessInstance where status ='Removed'` SOQL

Comment: Please tell me one thing, what is the difference between removed and recalled which word i use in where condition e.g where status='Removed' or where status='Recalled'

Comment: I don't think Recalled will work. Once the record id removed from approval it will change the status to Removed

Comment: how can i access this object through UI, I can't see this object in object manager.

Comment: You wont be able to see this object in object manager as you cannot customise this. Please find the below [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_processinstance.htm) for the object reference which shows you can use it in query(), retrieve()

Answer (score 1):

For the records that are recalled you will have status as "Removed" you can use the below SOQL to get the records that are recalled.

```
SELECT Id, Status, TargetObject.type, CompletedDate FROM ProcessInstance where status ='Removed'
```